# Can I embed a SharePoint or Outlook Calendar in a Sway?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-calendar, outlook

I'm trying to include a calendar within a Sway.

The calendar will be updated remotely but if it must be updated within the Sway that's fine as well.

Is there a way to even put a calendar within Sway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my research, Sway does not support embedding content from **Outlook**.

**Source**: [Embed content in your Sway](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/embed-content-in-your-sway-1e1ab12a-f961-4a26-8afc-77a15f892b1d)

Also,

> Sway currently supports the embedding of Word, Excel, and PowerPoint documents including individual charts/tables from Excel documents stored on OneDrive, OneDrive for work or school, or **SharePoint**.

**Source**: [Embed an Office document in Sway](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/embed-an-office-document-in-sway-a860fe56-6308-4dc4-9b26-072c7f3b51f0)

So, it does not support embedding calendar list from SharePoint.

Comment: Ah ok, that's a shame, thank you for your help